# Hover effect not working with CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I got on my website a nice ToTop button, As you can see here:

```
The following link is with css transition
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zvz6G/

I got some nice hover effect but the problem is that by using the Transition to get my nice looking hover effect i am losing my fadeIn/fadeOut effects to show the problem, Here is the same code as above just without transition:

```
The following link is without css transition
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tGeh2/

As you can see now i got my fadeIn/fadeOut effects but i am **losing** my hover effect, **My question is**: what is the reason for that and how can i fix it, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you include some code in your question. Don't avoid the rules.

Comment: For me, the code is working perfectly. I have tried the second fiddle. And hover was good, fadeIn/fadeOut was perfect. What is the issue buddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, You can define a new class which disable **CSS Transitions** and add it to your **scroll to top** buttons before starting `fadeOut` effect, then remove them when `fadeOut` effect completed, I have changed your code and **fixed your issue**, you can see my changes in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvz6G/16/).

Comment: Note: I have implemented this fix only for `fadeOut` effect, you can implement it for `fadein` effect if you need that

Comment: Thank you Alireza, Mabye you know why transition and fade can't work together?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure that my thought about this issue is true or not, so I prefer to not talk about it.

Comment: Thank you, If i may, I also didn't understand why do i have to use both body and html selectors $("html, body") on the click even?, Thanks again.

Comment: Using `html, body` in click event is a fix for browser compatibility, some browser apply overall scroll to `html` element, but others apply it to `body` element, so for getting a cross browser result, you should apply scroll animation to both of them.

Comment: So for some browser if i define only html the click even won't return to the top and for some others if i define only body the click won't work?

Comment: Yes, for example if you run your code on a Webkit/Blink based browser like Google Chrome, `body` works well and it's not needed to use `html`, but it *may not work* in some browser such very old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you well explained, I appreciate all thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the css and added it using jquery.
http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/Zvz6G/25/embedded/result/

Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/Zvz6G/25/

```
$('.scrollUp').hover(function () {
    $('.scrollUp').fadeOut(500).delay(100);
});

$('.scrollUp').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.scrollUp').fadeIn(500).delay(100);
});
```

Hope this helps.
This will be supported by all browsers, preventing inconsistencies in ie etc.